# Listening with a script to tcpdump output pcaps

Tags: python, linux, tcpdump

I have a `tcpdump` process on a redhat sever which continously  captures traffic from its `NIC`. The tcpdump starts a new capture  file every 1MB. The capture files are accessible via a samba share.

I am writing a python script which reads the `pcap` files from the share and  processes them.

The problem is that tcpdump does  not lock the file which is currently being written (it's definitely the tcpdump and not the samba server). Therefore, I don't know if  the file is still being written to while my script start processing it. Moreover, the `tcpdump` can be closed abruptly, therefore I prefer not to count on the file size as an indicator.

Answer (score 1):

what about `os.path.getmtime`? This can be used to get the last modification time.

Or you could pipe the stream from tcpdump to your own process which `tee`s the data to your own files, and buffer.

`tcpdump | python some_script.py`

And some_script.py or something similar:

```
import fileinput
import sys
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
s = SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=1024, prefix='saves_', dir='/some/dir')
for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[1:]):
    # write to spooled buffer
    s.write(line)
    # tee back to stdout
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

`SpooledTemporaryFile` creates a buffer.

`fileinput.input` can read from `stdin` or can take a list of files like:

- `python some_script.py /some/file.input.txt` ... OR
- `tcpdump | python some_script.py`

`sys.argv[1:]` is used to grab the files as a list, if they are listed.